# Birth Record for Anders Johansson Kålander (Finland)

Tags: birth-records, baptism-records, 1810s, finland

Anders Johansson Kålander was born on 22 September 1810. He appears on the 1855-1862 Communion Record for Kokkola Parish with his wife, Caisa, and his 3 children.

I've already searched the Kokkola Parish records but I haven't been able to find a birth record for Anders.

Answer (score -3):

A detailed answer was posted on Facebook finnish genealogy page

https://www.facebook.com/groups/14108279806/permalink/10159674593764807/

Comment: Hi H. Maki, this link-only answer is not helpful because (a) the link is to a private page and (b) the link has the possibility to go stale / become invalid ("link rot"). You could improve this answer by summarizing the contents of the page.

Comment: It's not possible to read that link without joining a Facebook group so can you summarize what it says in your answer, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo It is considered bad form to share information from private Facebook Groups outside the group. I would not share information that I saw in a private Facebook Group without explicit permission from the author.  I agree with the vote to delete this answer.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment @JanMurphy but if the user treads cautiously I think there's still a chance they may be able to improve their answer.